# Changing and saving content inside info window after close

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have a map that geocodes locations retrieved from JSON and sticks a marker on the map.

The markers also have an infowindow that shows the markers name and rating.

There's a button inside an infowindow that increments a rating counter when you click a button.

The initial counter is retrieved from JSON.

Annoyingly, when the info window closed and reopen, the counter value resets.

I tried populating an object with all of the marker ratings, updating the object when the button is clicked and then output the rating from the object inside the contentString for the infowindow. This didn't work and the same initial rating counter was shown after re-opening the infowindow.

My code is below, any help would be appreciated.

```
var map;
var geocoder;
var infowindow;
var rating;

function initMap() {
    var mapElement = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.481949, -2.237430),
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
}

$(document).on('click', '#been-there', function(event){
    var entryID = $(this).data('entry-id');
    var rating = $(this).data('rating');
    var dataString = 'id='+ entryID;

    rating++;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "db-been-there.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
    }).success(function(html){
        console.log(html);
    }).fail(function(html){
        console.log(html);
    });

    $('#rating').html(rating);

});

$.getJSON("db-output.php", function(dbJSON) {
    $.each(dbJSON, function(key, data) {

        var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + data.lat + "," + data.lng + "&result_type=sublocality|political&key=AIzaSyCsY-LOPL7dGbA1ShBEu7zMO8_GaSBA3Vg";

        $.getJSON(url, function(reverseGeo) {
            var postal_town = reverseGeo.results[0].formatted_address;

            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': postal_town}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == 'OK') {

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        title: data.name
                    });

                    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                        '<h1>' + data.name + '</h1>' +
                        '<button id="been-there" data-rating="' + data.rating + '" data-entry-id="' + data.id + '">Seen it</button>' +
                        '<p><strong>Rating: </strong><span id="rating">' + data.rating + '</span></p>' +
                        '</div>';

                    marker.addListener('click', function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });

                } else {
                    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

---

**EDIT: Resolved code and JSFiddle below**

**Resolved JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/BleepyEvans/3czqmqav/

```
var locations = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Location 1",
        "lat": "53.408371",
        "lng": "-2.991573",
        "rating": "17"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Location 2",
        "lat": "53.789528",
        "lng": "-2.969411",
        "rating": "8"
    },
]

var map;
var geocoder;
var infowindow;
var rating;
var markers = [];

function initMap() {
    var mapElement = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.481949, -2.237430),
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
}

$(document).on('click', '#been-there', function(event){
    var entryID = $(this).data('entry-id');
    var dataString = 'id='+ entryID;

    rating = markers[entryID].rating;
    rating++;

    markers[entryID].rating = rating;

        console.log(markers[entryID].rating);

    $('#rating').html(rating);

});

$.each(locations, function(key, data) {

    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + data.lat + "," + data.lng + "&result_type=sublocality|political&key=AIzaSyCsY-LOPL7dGbA1ShBEu7zMO8_GaSBA3Vg";

    $.getJSON(url, function(reverseGeo) {
        var postal_town = reverseGeo.results[0].formatted_address;

        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': postal_town}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    title: data.name,
                    rating: data.rating
                });

                markers[data.id] = marker;

                console.log(markers[data.id].rating);

                marker.addListener('click', function() {
                        var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                    '<h1>' + data.name + '</h1>' +
                    '<button id="been-there" data-rating="' + data.rating + '" data-entry-id="' + data.id + '">Been There</button>' +
                    '<p><strong>Rating: </strong><span id="rating">' + markers[data.id].rating + '</span></p>' +
                    '</div>';

                    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });

            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than just create an HTML string which includes the rating data that you assign to your infowindow, I'd add the rating value to the Marker object itself.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: results[0].geometry.location,
    title: data.manufacturer_name,
    rating: data.rating
});
```

Save those markers in an object keyed on their ID:

```
markers[data.id] = marker;
```

Then when the user clicks the button, update that value:

```
$(document).on('click', '#been-there', function(event){
    var entryID = $(this).data('entry-id');
    rating = markers[entryID].rating;
    rating++;
```

And update the value on the Marker:

```
markers[entryID].rating = rating;
```

If it doesn't work directly accessing the `rating` property on the markers, you might need to use:

```
markers[entryID].get('rating');
markers[entryID].set('rating', rating);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply duncan. I've followed all of the above, but I still get the same output as before. The rating increases on click but doesn't persist after the info window is closed. Can I confirm that in the contentString variable which sets the content of the info window, that I have `markers[data.id].rating` instead of data.rating in my original question please?

Comment: @OliverEvans yes that would make sense

Comment: So I've added my code with your solution implemented to help us find out why its not working. Please can you let me know what you think? https://jsfiddle.net/BleepyEvans/3czqmqav/

Comment: so it looks like when the infowindow loads, it loads the initial rating value instead of from the markers object.